# Swift encode class containing another class

Tags: swift, class, nscoding

I'm trying to encode data in a class with swift but my class contains another class. Is it possible to encode the second class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. It just should also implement `NSCoding`. For example my FQGetPermissionOperation includes and encodes/decodes a FQUploadTask object. FQUploadTask also implements NSCoding and inherits NSObject.

```
class FQGetPermissionOperation : NSObject, NSCoding {
let uploadTask: FQUploadTask

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    uploadTask = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("uploadTask") as! FQUploadTask
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(uploadTask, forKey: "uploadTask")
    super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
}
// Some other code
}
```